# Are there any quadratic functions on an abelian variety not from the height machine?

Tags: nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, heights

Let $X$ be an abelian variety defined over a number field $K$. We know that the Neron--Tate height machine associates to a class in the Picard group of $X$ a unique quadratic function which is zero at the identity of $X$. And it is known that modulo torsion this association homomorphism is injective. Consider the homomorphism
$$
h:\text{Pic}(X_{\bar K})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{ \text{quadratic real functions on }X(\bar K)\text{ which vanish at the identity} \}.
$$My question is, is this homomorphism surjective (and an isomorphism?)?

I'm asking this out of curiosity mainly. I don't know if this is well-known to the experts (or just another silly question of mine). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is the homomorphism injective?

Comment: @Will Sawin: Dear Will, I am not sure if this is correct actually. My question should have two consecutive question marks there.

Comment: OK, I confirm that after tensoring with $\mathbb{R}$, the map is still injective, which is actually quite easy to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source has countable dimension over $\mathbb R$, since $A$ has countably many divisors defined over a finite extension of $K$, while the target, being the space of quadratic functions on a countably-infinite-dimensional vector space, has uncountable dimension over $\mathbb R$, so the map can never be surjective.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear on it. I really mean the map from the infinite dimensional space to the infinite dimensional space. The quadratic function here could contain a linear part, so for example, an algebraically trivial line bundle can give a nonzero linear function. The reference I'm looking at is Lang's Fundamentals of Diophantine geometry, chapter 5.

Comment: @userunknown See edited version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know very little about functional analysis; is there an easy way to think about this fact: "the space of quadratic functions on a countably-infinite-dimensional vector space has uncountable dimension"? Is it also true for linear functions?

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure why this second point is correct: if we take a (countable) real basis of $X(\bar K)\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}$, the quadratic function as a sum of linear form and quadratic form, with the quadratic form determined by the induced inner product, seems that it can be determined by countably many values. Why is it uncountable?

Comment: @userunknown Yes, it's also true for linear functions. Exactly for the reason you say: A linear function on a countable-dimensional vector space is determined by countably many values, i.e. it's the product $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ of countably many copies of $\mathbb R$. But that product does not have countable dimension, i.e. it lacks a countable basis.

Comment: @userunknown If it had a countable basis, it could have only countably many linearly independent vectors (at most $n$ using each set of $n$ basis vectors, and there are countably many sets of $n$ basis vectors for all $n$) but in fact the vectors $(1,t,t^2,\dots)$ are linearly independent for all real $t$.

Comment: I see! So the point is, a linear function on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is basically an infinite real vector with no restriction on the coordinates. The space of linear functions is not a direct sum but a direct product. That's very helpful. Thanks a lot!